# How to expose java object to LuaJ

Tags: java, lua, scripting, luaj

I've recently started learning Lua because I need to use it in a Java application I'm working on. For this I'm using LuaJ. I've searched around on the internet and found out how you can expose a Java method to LuaJ but I can't find out how to expose (give LuaJ access to) a Java object. I saw another post about exposing C# objects to Lua and the answer was this:

> The general method of sharing objects between Lua and any application in any language is to define the `__index()` and `__newindex()` metamethods (and possibly others) of a `userdata`...

Could someone either explain to me how to do what is described here or explain another way to expose objects so I can basically do something like this:

```
//In Java.
exposeObject(myObject, "nameOfMyObject");

--Then in Lua
nameOfMyObject:myFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to check out the Class "CoerceJavaToLua". It contains a method called "coerce()" which takes an object and creates a LuaValue representation of the object, which you can then add to your globals. As an example:

Java:

```
LuaValue luaObject = CoerceJavaToLua.coerce(myObject);
globals.set("nameOfMyObject", luaObject);
```

Lua:

```
nameOfMyObject:someFunction()
```

"globals" should be your Globals instance you created earlier. Do this before loading a file or loading from string.

If you wish more manually, LuaJ does offer a way to get a LuaValue of any java object from within lua:

```
local obj = luajava.newinstance("your.package.YourClass", "argument1", 2)
```

To access static fields or use Enums use bindClass instead of newInstance, bindClass takes no arguments other than the package and class name.

For more info check out:

http://www.luaj.org/luaj/3.0/README.html#5

and

http://www.luaj.org/luaj/3.0/README.html#luajava